# Removing punctuation from strings?

Tags: javascript, string, methods, formula, reduce

I'm working on a palindrome function and have come across a formula which removes punctuation from strings.

```
var punctuation = /[\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]/g;
var spaceRE = /\s+/g;
var str = "randomstringwith*&^%"
var testStr = str.replace(punctuation, '').replace(spaceRE, '')
document.write(testStr);
```

My question is that If I remove the `.replace(spaceRE, '')` nothing seems to change in the result. Is there something I'm missing or does this formula have excess code on it? also I'm slightly confused about the use of `str.replace(punctuation,'');`

`punctuation` represents any non letter/number characters and the `''` replaces them with an empty string, correct? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some sample data and explain why the replacement is not happening as expected?

Comment: In your case, it would be far easier to write a pattern that includes what you *do* want rather than what you don't. If you want to allow only numbers and letters you can use `str.replace(/\W/g, '')`

Comment: Nothing changes in your result because `spaceRE` is here to remove all spaces or white space, and you have none in you input. Also wondering why you didn't simply use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of both regexes..

Comment: If one of you would mind answering so I can mark solved. I've only started learning about regexes tonight so I'm not familiar with much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In situations like yours you have to ask yourself which is easier:

- Create a REGEXP that **blocks** certain characters
- Create a REGEXP that **allows** certain characters

The choice you opt for should depend on which is less work and be more reliable.

Writing a pattern that blocks all symbols depends on you remembering every possible symbol - not just punctuation, but emoji patterns, mathematical symbols and so on.

If all you want is to allow numbers and letters only, you can do:

```
str.replace(/\W/g, '');
```

`\W`/ is an alias for "non-alphanumeric" characters. The only caveat here is alphanumeric includes underscores, so if you want to block those too:

```
str.replace(/\W|_/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `var spaceRE = /\s+/g;` removes all whitespaces from strings, while `punctuation` removes punctuation. Replacing both simultaneously with empty strings delivers a string with no punctuation or whitespaces and saves it to `testStr`